Issue with converting a C# project from .NET 4.8 to .NET 8.0
I've got a C# project that I started 4 or 5 months ago. I started it on Visual Studio 2022 and the project uses C# and Windows Forms.
I worked on it a little bit and left it. Now I've come back to it. I wanted to continue coding, but I stumbled upon the problem where I see this error:

feature default interface implementation is not available in c# 7.3

I found I've been using an older .NET 4.8 version. I changed the target framework in my .csproj file by adding <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework> and also <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>, as well as removing the older TargetFramework.
Then I had a problem with "duplicate compile items", so I added <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false<\EnableDefaultCompileItems> and <EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems>false<\EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems>.
Now, I no longer get that problem, but sadly I have other issues I can't resolve.
Firstly, I get these two messages:

The file does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports this code

I also have almost 200 errors that all look like this:

The type or namespace does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference)

(I've seen this link, but my framework is indeed 8.0).

The type name could not be found in the namespace. This type has been forwarded to assembly... Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

All the problems seem to be related to Forms, since all the errors I've clicked so far point me to a line like this:
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn totalSpacesDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;

I assume it has something to do with the 2 messages that are telling me I have a problem with 2 of the forms. I also tried to add references, but that didn't work.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Realistically, it's not that much of a problem to start the project again, but I don't want to do the forms all over again, since it took some time.
Edit: Since the initial post, I've read and tried things from the comments. After adding <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework> and <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms> I no longer get this problem

The file does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports this code

I don't get the other issue with Forms, but now I get it on other parts of the code AirportSystemDataSet and AirportSystemDataSetTableAddapter. Example:

The type or namespace namespace AirportSystemDataSet could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Finally, I also get this warning

Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.

Edit 2.0(Answer to the questions): I managed to get my project to run.
The issue with the dataset was fixed by commenting out code refering to and deleting all components that were datasets. After that my forms no longer showed errors.
In order to fix the other issue I needed to remove this block of code from the .csproj file:
<COMReference Include="System_Windows_Forms">
    <Guid>{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}</Guid>
    <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
    <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
</COMReference>

I also had some errors regarding duplicate assemblies which I also just commented out. I tried to run the project and it worked.

EnableDefaultEmbeddetResourceItems has typo, it should be EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems

<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework> <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>. Did you actually migrate to the SDK style, i.e., you have <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> on top of the .csproj file? -- What is v 4.2?

@MichałTurczyn that is a spelling error that I made in writting the question here, the actual one is indeed with a d.

@Jimi I do have <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> on top of the .csproj file. I did not have the <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms> tag. Now that I added it, I no longer get any of the old errors/warnings but instead I get Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library ... Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly. Any ideas on how to fix that?

@Jimi Also, the v4.2 was a typo. It was actually v4.8. By that I mean that my TargetFramework was that. The code line used to be <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>. Now I changed it to <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>

Already mentioned, the target framework must be net8.0-windows. net8.0 is good for a Console application

The .NET Upgrade assistant is an extension you can install in Visual Studio which will upgrade the project for you and make any required changes and/or warn you of incompatibilities. I'd recommend rolling back to the pure 4.8 version (you do use source control, I hope) and then letting it have a go, rather than manually hacking around the project file.

Upgrade Assistant

OK how about you change your post to reflect what errors you are currently seeing, because it's very unclear at the moment what your current issue is.

@jimi Adding the -windows, fixed one of the problems, which was the error with loaiding the form. I still have issues with Failed to create wrapper... and also certain assemblies. Also, certain attributes seem to be duplicated like System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute

@Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not using source control and I don't think I can go back to a previous version of the file. I've changed it and saved it, closed it and event turned of my pc, so I'm not sure if there are any ways to go back to what it was. Any suggestions on how to do that, or if I should just try using the upgrade assitant on the current file I have?

@Charlieface I made an edit.

I don't know what the Failed to create wrapper [...] thing is related to, could be anything, you have to be precise. You might have third-party libraries / other Projects that are targeting .NET Framework. You should remove all packages and reinstall all anyway, picking compatible distributions -- You probably still have AssemblyInfo.cs in the Properties folder. That should also be migrated to the SDK model, where that information is included in the .csproj file

@Jimi Ok, I will try and see what I can do there. I have another question. My initial reasoning for making the post is that I didn't want to spend that much time recreating the forms all over again. At this point I feel like I am wasting more time trying to upgrade the project. Would it work if I create another project from scratch and just add the Forms files, or would that create potential errors/issues in the future?

You can do that, of course. But it depends on what assemblies you're referencing in your Forms. If, as mentioned, you're using third-party assemblies (or others of your own creation) that target .NET Framework, the problem comes back. You can remove all references to these packages, then use NuGet Package Manager to reinstall those packages. But something may have changed, in the meantime. So, no guarantee it's going to be a smooth transition anyway (not even with the Upgrade Assistant, though, it's not magic)

@Jimi I fixed the issue with the wrapper by removing another tag section in the .csproj file. It was this.
    <Guid>{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}</Guid>
    <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
    <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
</COMReference>```
I also managed to fix all the errors by commenting out all dataset related code and now the project finally works. Thanks for the help

Hello, it seems that you have found a solution to your problem. You can share it as an answer for others to take a reference.  @Ineffable21

@FeiXu I just did, thanks for the suggestion.

I managed to find an answer to my question from the comments and google searches. Here is explanation on what I did, in case other people have similar problems. First problem:

The file does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports this code

In order to get rid of this error I had to add these tags in order ot upgrade the project properly:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework> 
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>

This also fixed the problem with namespaces that was related to Forms. Second problem, which was similar for the Forms namespace problem, but for dataset objects:

The type or namespace does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference)


The type name could not be found in the namespace. This type has been forwarded to assembly... Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

In order to fix this problem I had to remove and comment out any dataset related code. After that if I tried to add anything data related it didn't have the same problems. I assume that the problem was occuring because of changes in the components with the new releases. Then the other issue that was occuring was this:

Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.

In order to fix this, I had to open the .csproj file and remove this code:
<COMReference Include="System_Windows_Forms">
    <Guid>{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}</Guid>
    <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
    <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
</COMReference>

I also had some errors regarding duplicate assemblies which I also just commented out. I tried to run the project and it worked.

I upgraded my framework applications using the .NET Upgrade Assistant. Worked very well for my WPF apps and class libraries. Decently for a Forms project I tried.

I tried that. To be honest it didn't really work that well. It made me downloand .net 9.0 and the core version as well, just to have the error list tell me that I don't have what I need to support 9.0. Afterwards I went back to 8.0 and did some other stuff which made my program work. I think that your answer would have helped if I never "upgraded" it by changing tags in the .csproj file.

Yeah, I meant to suggest you "Downgrade manually" first :)

.NET 4.8 and .NET 8 have many design differences, particularly in API and runtime. While .NET 8 remains compatible with many .NET Framework features, differences in runtime, APIs, and tools may necessitate adjustments.  Microsoft offers tools and documentation to assist with migration, but careful planning and testing are essential.
The following can help you understand API differences and resolve compatibility issues of project migration to .NET 8:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-8.0
